# How to unmark a duplicate for restarting flow though inbound that has prevent duplicates set

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

The question is, in spring integration, the inbound adapter has `preventDuplicates(true)` , how does this work under the hood? The reason for the question being, in case a flow is interrupted and does not complete for some exceptions raised in either terminal or intermediary service activators, the inbound should be able to pick this up again.

Answer (score 1):

It configures an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` by default, which only protects against duplicates with an in-memory Map.

If you explicitly inject an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` (or a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which can store the state in a persistent store), you can call `remove()` - they both implement `ResettableFileListFilter`.

```
/**
 * A {@link FileListFilter} that can be reset by removing a specific file from its
 * state.
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 4.1.7
 *
 */
public interface ResettableFileListFilter<F> extends FileListFilter<F> {

    /**
     * Remove the specified file from the filter so it will pass on the next attempt.
     * @param f the element to remove.
     * @return true if the file was removed as a result of this call.
     */
    boolean remove(F f);

}
```